# C# Wpf Image Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, изображения, binding

Как биндит Image? Поля типа string и bool  отображаются, а Image не отображается. C#,WPF

```
<av:Window x:Class="MessengerVK.MessageManager"
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
       xmlns:av="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
       xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
       xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
       xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:MessengerVK.ViewModel"
       Title="MessageManager"
       Width="640"
       Height="480"
       mc:Ignorable="d">
<Window.DataContext>
    <viewModel:MessageManagerViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<av:Grid ShowGridLines="True">
    <av:Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <av:ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
        <av:ColumnDefinition Width="4*" />
        <av:ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
    </av:Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <av:Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <av:RowDefinition Height="1*" />
        <av:RowDefinition Height="2*" />
        <av:RowDefinition Height="6*" />
        <av:RowDefinition Height="2*" />
    </av:Grid.RowDefinitions>        
    <ListView Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <ListViewItem>  
           <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
               <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Width="70" Text="{Binding Path=Template.Name}"/>
               <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Width="50" Text="{Binding Path=Template.Online}"/>
               <Image Grid.Column="2" Width="70" Height="70" Source="{Binding Path=Template.Avatar}"/>
             </Grid>
        </ListViewItem>
    </ListView>       
    </Grid>
</av:Grid>
```

```
public class Friend
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Online { get; set; }
    public Image Avatar { get; set; }
}


public class MessageManagerViewModel:ViewModelBase,INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private Friend template;
    public Friend Template
    {
        get
        {
            return template;
        }

        set
        {
            template = value;
        }
    }

    public MessageManagerViewModel()
    {

        Template.Name = "Azizxon";
        Template= Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\a.png");


    }


}
```

Comment: А зачем вам namespace `av`?

Answer (score 1):

Для приложений на WPF пользуйтесь в VM не `System.Drawing.Image`, а [`System.Windows.Media.BitmapImage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Дело в том, что вы пользуетесь контролом `System.Windows.Controls.Image`, и привязываетесь к его свойству [`Source`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.source%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Это свойство имеет тип [`ImageSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imagesource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), а `System.Drawing.Image` не является наследником `ImageSource`.